# Can't get jquery validate to work with jquery ajaxform and progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have this very simple form:

```
<form id="file-form" action="student-files.php?userId=<?php echo $userId ;?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<strong>Title:</strong><br />
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="">
<span id="invalid-title" class="errormsg"></span>
<br /><br />

<strong>File:</strong><br />
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" value="null">
<span id="invalid-file1" class="errormsg"></span>
<br /><br />

<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>
<div id="status"></div>
<br /><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add File">
</form>
```

I'm trying to use validate and ajaxform at the same time so that I can have an upload progress bar.  I have found several answers on here that are similar but none of them are working for me.

If I completely remove the validate call then the progress bar updates and the file uploads.  If I keep the validate call in then the progress bar does not update but the file does upload.

It's just the visual part of the progress bar that's not working, I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Here's my JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#file-form').validate({
        rules: {
            file1: {
                required: true,
                extension: "pdf",
            },
        },
        messages: {
            file1: "File must be PDF",
        },
        onkeyup: false,
        onfocusout: false,
        onclick: false,
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo('#invalid-' + element.attr('id'));
    }
    });

    var bar = $('.bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var status = $('#status');


    $('#file-form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: function () {
            status.empty();
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
            return $('#file-form').valid();
        },
        uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        complete: function () {
            bar.width("100%");
            percent.html("100%");
            window.location.replace("student-files.php?userId=<?php echo $userId ;?>")
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to put your `ajaxForm()` function inside of the `submitHandler` callback option of the jQuery Validate plugin.  [As per the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler), the `submitHandler` is the *"right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated"*.

Something more like this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#file-form').validate({
        rules: {
            file1: {
                required: true,
                extension: "pdf",
            },
        },
        messages: {
            file1: "File must be PDF",
        },
        onkeyup: false,
        onfocusout: false,
        onclick: false,
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo('#invalid-' + element.attr('id'));
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxForm({
                // your options
            });
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```